# Css filter: Wikipedia: Inline math's background is not transparent

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, filter

The other day I had fun writing a Chrome Extension for creating a dark mode for Wikipedia. It went all well, but then I noticed some artifacts:

[Screenshop snippet of artifacts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCE7B.png)

The corresponding html is:

```
<span class="texhtml">
<i>ω</i>
<span style="position:relative; 
    margin-right:-0.75em; 
    right:0.75em; 
    bottom:0.75em;;">
        <small>→</small>
</span>
```

... from website: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity

I am not able to find any background css setting for this span or any other node inside it... When I do change background settings in my extension, nothing happens.

Here is the css file loaded by my extension:

```
:root                                                                              
{                                                                                  
    /* COLOR DEFINITONS */                                                         

    /* Color palette from hackaday.com */                                          
    --background: rgb(30,30,30);                                                   
    --text: rgb(221,221,221);                                                      
    --border: rgb(72,72,72);                                                       
    --links: rgb(23,168,250);                                                      
}                                                                                  

/* Remove top banner */                                                            
#cnotice-main                                                                      
{                                                                                  
    display: none !important;                                                      
}                                                                                  

/* Borders */                                                                      
*                                                                                  
{                                                                                  
    border-color: var(--border) !important;                                        
}                                                                                  

/* Links */                                                                        
a                                                                                  
{                                                                                  
    color: var(--links) !important;                                                
}                                                                                  

/* Invert Wikipedia Logo */                                                        
#p-logo                                                                            
{                                                                                  
    filter: invert(100%) !important;                                               
}                                                                                  

/* Change colors where appropriate */                                              
body, #content,                                                                    
*[class~='navbox'], td, #simpleSearch,                                             
*[class^='suggestions'], *[class^='special-'], input,                              
#mw-head, table, div[id='catlinks'], div[class^='thumb'],                          
table[class^='wikitable'], th, span[class='tocnumber'],                            
*[id^='p-namespaces'], *[id^='p-view'], span, li,                                  
div[class^='mw-'], *[class^='Nav'],                                                
*[id^='mwe-popup'],                                                                
*[class^='mwe-popup'],                                                             
*[id^='mp-'], div[id='toc'],                                                       
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6                                                             
{                                                                                  
    background-image: none !important;                                             
    background-color: var(--background) !important;                                
    background: var(--background) !important;                                                                                                              
    color: var(--text) !important;                                                 
}                                                                                  

/* DOES NOT WORK, i.e. background is still solid grey. */                          
[class='texhtml']                                                                  
{                                                                                  
    background rgb(0,0,0,0.5) !important;                                          
}                                                                                  

/* Latex formulae */                                                               
.mwe-math-fallback-image-inline                                                    
{                                                                                  
    filter: invert(100%);                                                          
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your CSS you set the background for every span.

You should exclude that tags from your selector: instead applying background to every `<span>` tag, you should try:

```
span:not(.texhtml),
span:not(.texhtml) span
```

Comment: Thanks man! Replacing `span` with `span:not(.texhtml) span` did the trick! :)